# Absolute Imports not working with WebPack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to setup up absolute imports, but it seems my webpack configs are wrong and the entry point it starts from is relative and not from ./src

I've looked through the webpack docs and they recommend adding an entry point, which I have but still nothing.

Error I get:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'contexts' in '/Users/gurneet/Desktop/Projects/projectfrontend/src/components/Home'

structure:

```
Project
|- src
     | - components 
         | - Home
              | - Featured.tsx
     | - contexts
         | - index.ts
         | - AllDataProvider.tsx
|-package.json
|-tsconfig.json
|-webpack.config.js
```

---

```
    // FEATURED.TSX
import React from 'react';
import {useData} from '../../contexts';  // this works
import {useData} from 'contexts'; // this doesn't work.
```

Even though when I hover over both the imports they points to the say index.ts file that has all the exports.

```
// WEBPACK
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  entry: './src',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg/,
        use: {
          loader: 'svg-url-loader',
          options: {
            // make all svg images to work in IE
            iesafe: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'public/_redirects' },
      ],
    }),
  ],

};
```

---

```
//TSCONFIG 

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Did you comment out the first import when hovering? If only the module name is provided it should be taken from the `node_modules` folder. Also as far as I know when working with typescript you should use the `export` key like described here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: @VincentMenzel yh the first import is commented out, i added it there to show the working and non working. 

and my context files does uses export (not default exports)

Comment: You probably want to use aliasing?

Comment: If there is notpackage with the name `contexts` in your `node_modules` the compiler won't be able to find it either. This is also not an absolute path. `/home/vincent/example.ts` is absolute `./example.ts` is relative `contexts` refers to a package which is installed and contains a module.

Comment: I got it, I updated my webpack config and added: 

"
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    modules: ['node_modules', path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
  },
"
this seems to have solved the issues.